# stand by operation in android tablet

Tags: android

I tried to do this.When anybody doesn't touch on the screen in android tablet after 5 minutes I want to bring a photo on screen and it will be show until anyone touches the screen.How can I do this.I developed an android application I need to add this feature in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do that is to create a stand alone activity that contains only the Image you want to display, like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

then in the `onCreate` of any currently regular running activity, run the following method:

```
public class YOUR_ACTIVITY extends Activity {

public static int x = 0; // must be static

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       run_thread();
}

private void run_thread(){
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(x < 5000){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                x++;
            }
            //Image.Class is the Activity that contains just the Image
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Image.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXIT, false);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

then Override the `onTouchEvent` for that Activity with the following:

```
@Override 
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        x = 0;
        return true;
    }
```

then Override the `onTouchEvent` of the `Image` activity so that when anyone touch it, it runs the `YOUR_ACTIVITY` activity with setting `x` to **0**.

to return to `YOUR_ACTIVITY` from the `Image` activity, override the `onTouchEvent` method in the `Image` activity like the following:

```
@Override 
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        YOUR_ACTIVITY.x = 0;
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    YOUR_ACTIVITY.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXIT, false);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: I tryed this but it doesn't work .I created other class it name is Image and I onTouchEvent but it doesn't work override.Can you write Image class??

Comment: @Rıdvan you assigned `onCreate()` to it with `setContentView(R.layout.image_layout);` ?

Comment: thank you it works but when it goes Image Activity I want to come back ( to Your Activity )class I tried to again onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) method and Intent in this method but each time it loads Image Activity it doesn't return Why??

Comment: @Rıdvan look at my new updates at the end of the answer